# Is there a recommended way to update version bounds on cabal packages?

Tags: haskell, cabal

With the release of GHC 7.10 and the accompanying version bump on the `base` package I found myself in the situation that I needed to fix my library dependencies.

For the moment I have run `cabal install --allow-newer` which found a set of working versions and installed fine.

Now I am in the process of manually searching through the installed libraries and updating the cabal files version bounds by hand.

Is there an easier/automatic way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I regularly use [`packdeps`](http://packdeps.haskellers.com/) to check on my dependencies and bump any that are too restrictive. As well as the website, there's a [hackage package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/packdeps) so you can run it locally.

Once I bump a dependency, e.g. by bumping `foo < 1.5` to `foo < 1.6`, I build and test locally using the `--constraint 'foo>=1.5'` argument to `cabal`, to check that the new version does indeed work.

Comment: Looks good, will wait for more answers before accepting this.

Comment: Have tried the `packdeps` commandline tool now. Nice tool to have.

Answer (score 3):

You might like the tool [cabal-bounds](https://github.com/dan-t/cabal-bounds).

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.